# Open a HTML-OS Database (DB4/DB5) and parse/read in c# application

Tags: c#, html, database, parsing

I have a task at hand, read a database that was created with HTML-OS, i assume the format is DB4 or DB5. the task is to open and parse this database in a c# application...it can be ASP.NET or WinForms...bottom line is i need to extract this indexed data. below is a small sample of what it looks like when i open the file with notepad:

dbtype 3.046  =     0 T ¨j

I have some ideas on parsing with possibly using RegEx but i would like to see some ideas or a real way of reading this file would be even better!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the database format is partially defined on their site:
[The HTML/OS Database (PDF)](https://www.htmlos.org/website/v2/docs/awsoft/03.pdf)

If possible I'd look at using their HTML/OS language to export it, rather than trying to reverse-engineer the database format.

Comment: im not really trying to reverse -engineer the DB...possibly write a RegEx function to access records... i didnt know if a wrapper existed, but as you mentioned exporting the record directly from the HTML/OS DB could be a scenario we havnt explored yet... do you now if HTML/OS will accept an HTTP Post? this post could contain an item number we want, then from that post HTML/OS could return our data in a structure of some sort....???

Comment: @Don - No idea. I got the information from [www.htmlos.org](https://www.htmlos.org); you may find more details there.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an htmlos page that would export the data from the database and store this in a csv for example. Then pick up the file from the other machine, after which you could execute something else to remove the csv file.

To answer devHead's question.. yes, HTML/OS accepts http posts.
(Just FYI: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.. I program in html/os.)